# Ionic cordova-plugin-contacts not installed but he is. Xcode 10

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for many hours now and it is very frustrating.

I am currently trying to create an application with ionic that gathers some information. One of the first is to retrieve the contacts from my phone.

For this purpose, I was told to use "cordova-plugin-contacts".

So I installed this plugin in my ionic project and when I want to access the contact recovery page it tells me that the plugin is not installed (see photo)

[image: Plugin installed]

My config:

- Xcode 10
- Ionic v4.2.1
- Cordova 8.1.2

I use ionic DevApp to test on my phone (iOS 12) because the emulator doesn't work, but that's a whole other story...

[image: Logs error]

Comment: [Please don't post your error and console messages as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: Have you solved this?